# I'm new to php and I was wondering how do you add font colour and style

Tags: php

I have this code which shows the date and time on my web page but I'm have trouble changing the font colour and style. I'm not sure how to go about doing this?

```
<?php echo date ('y-m-d H:i:s');?>
```

Comment: Think of PHP as something that simply spits out custom HTML pages to clients. PHP itself doesn't control how the data is displayed, but the HTML document it _produces_ does.

Comment: The exact same way of course, as if this was _not_ dynamically output by PHP, but you had typed a static date directly into an HTML document. How would you do it in this case ...? You would wrap it into some HTML element, maybe add a class to that element, and then format it via your stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS styles.

```
<?php
echo '<span style="color: red;">' . date('y-m-d H:i:s') . '</span>';
?>
```